# coq program module throws out my hypotheses

Tags: coq

EDIT: I fixed the issue by using subtypes, ie changing 
`forall(i: nat)` to

`forall(i: {n: nat | n <? length})`

but I would still like to know why the program module behaves like this and if there's anything I could have done about it. The two programs are logically equivalent, so it would be silly for one to type-check but the other not to.

I am trying to write this function

```
Program Fixpoint indomain_arr (m: mem) (a: array) :=
  match a with Array _ length => forall(i: nat), (i< length -> indomain m (inr(El a i))) end.
Obligation 1.
```

The specifics are not too important, I don't think, except for the fact that I have (i < length) as a hypothesis. When I proceed to obligation 1, the proof state is

```
  m : mem
  wildcard' : string
  length, i : nat
  ============================
  i <? length
```

which is annoying, as it doesn't include the hypothesis I put in the output proposition specifically so that I could solve this obligation. What is the fix for this? How can I bring that hypothesis back into my context?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem under some assumptions, but the Program Fixpoint command doesn't even leave an obligation.  Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . And because behaviors may depend on the version of coq you're using, please let me know the version.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code with coq 8.11.1.

```
Require Import Program.
Require Import Arith.

Inductive P (n : nat) : (n =? 0 = true) -> Prop :=
| P_intro : forall p, P n p.

Program Definition f (n : nat) : Prop :=
  forall (i : nat), i < n -> P i _.
Next Obligation.
```

This results in the proof state

```
  n, i : nat
  ============================
  (i =? 0) = true
```

which doesn't have `i < n` as an assumption.

I tried another definition of `f`.

```
Program Definition f (n : nat) : Prop :=
  forall (i : nat) (Hsmall : i < n), P i _.
Next Obligation.
```

(note that the hypothesis `i < n` is explicitly named as `Hsmall`)

Now I have the hypothesis in my proof state.

```
  n, i : nat
  Hsmall : i < n
  ============================
  (i =? 0) = true
```

Comment: Is this intended or a bug?